# Was this copyright claim determined to be bogus?

Tags: discussion

The deleted answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/250258/revisions) reads like a copyright infringement notice, although I'm confused as to what could be considered infringing. I did not try following the link... was it detected malicious?

Comment: It's spam, it's been hitting the site under different names and different links for a few weeks now.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Thank you. I figured as much, but this was the first I saw of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's been a whole load of these "answers" posted in recent months. Some links (answers deleted, only visible to 10k+ rep users, I can't be bothered to post screenshots as the content is pretty much the same every time):

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/250303/31394
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/250258/31394
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/247564/31394
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/247430/31394 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/246884/31394 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/246359/31394

Especially that last one isn't even trying to look genuine: three separate answers under three different names, posted to a Q&A that doesn't even contain an image.

So yes, bogus. And even if it wasn't, it's not something that we (users *or* moderators) can handle; copyright violations are a matter for SE the company to deal with. That's why Null has been leaving comments on these posts with the link to contact SE - just in case any legitimate complaint comes through, they get redirected to the right place.

Answer (score 10):

Yes these are spam posts. They've been showing up for at least a month. The format is always the same but the username (usually a "real" name) and link are different each time. Note that someone clicked the link (unfortunately) on one of the early ones and left the below comment which does confirm it pretty much:

> First of all, the answer box is not the place for this sort of thing. Secondly, what images are you alleging are being infringed? I see no images on this page that would belong to you, and the linked document is coming up blank for me.

A discussion in chat about these posts between myself, DavidW and Mithical also led to DavidW posting this main meta poposal: [Temporarily block (disable) links in spam-flagged posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363781/345161)

If you see these posts in the wild, please spam flag them.

Comment: And don't click the links!